# Instance method 'items' requires that 'listen' conform to 'Sequence'

Tags: swift, uitableview, bind, rx-swift

I want to bind the value of tableViewCell. But there is an error like the title. I've never seen this error before and I want to know how to fix it.

```
  func bindViewModel() {
        let input = ListenViewModel.input(loadData: loadData.asSignal(onErrorJustReturn: ()))
        let output = viewModel.transform(input)
        
        output.loadApplyList.bind(to: tableView.rx.items) { tableView, index, element -> UITableViewCell in
            guard let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ListeningTableViewCell") as? ListeningTableViewCell else {
                return ListeningTableViewCell()}
            cell.listeningData = element
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
    }
```

This is my ViewController Code

```
class ListenViewModel: ViewModelType {

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    static var loadData = PublishRelay<listen>()

    struct input {
        let loadData: Signal<Void>

    }
    struct output {
      //  let isEnabled: Driver<Bool>
        let result: Signal<String>
        let loadApplyList: PublishRelay<listen>
    

    }

    func transform(_ input: input) -> output {
        let api = ProfileAPI()
        let result = PublishSubject<String>()
        let loadApplyList = PublishRelay<listen>()
    

        input.loadData.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            api.getListenigList("admin123@gmail.com").subscribe(onNext: { (response, statuscode) in
                switch statuscode {
                case .ok:
                    if let response = response {
                        loadApplyList.accept(response)
                    }
                case .noHere: result.onNext("fail")
                default:
                    print("Default")
                }
            }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

        return output(result: result.asSignal(onErrorJustReturn: "실패"), loadApplyList: loadApplyList)
    }

}
```

And this is my ViewModel Code.
How to fix this error?

Comment: Do you just want to display one `ListeningTableViewCell` cell only?

Comment: On this screen, I would like to show the ListeningTabelViewCell only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind to a table view's `items`, you need a sequence of things, like an array, for example. Each element of that sequence will be displayed on a cell.

You've got a `listen` object here (`output.loadApplyList`), which isn't a sequence of things. If you just want to just display one cell, you should create a sequence with a single element.

There is a simple way to create a sequence with only a single element: [`CollectionOfOne`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collectionofone), so you should `map` your `listen` objects to that.

```
output.loadApplyList.map(CollectionOfOne.init).bind(to: tableView.rx.items) { ... }
```